# How to console log numbers from 1 to 1 million efficiently

Tags: javascript, memory-management

Javascript code that prints out (using console.log) a sequence of numbers from 1 to 1,000,000  without blocking the interactions with the browser. For example, while that piece of Javascript is running, mouse, keyboard events etc should work fine and browser doesn't hang.

Comment: Homework is fine but please read [ask] and especially [Asking about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @Kenny.Harrer this is a homework question, which is fine but the OP needs to make _some_ attempt at solving it themselves not just ask the internet to do it for them

Comment: @Jamiec Oh okay, but why did you down vote my answer?

Comment: @Kenny.Harrer What makes you think I downvoted your answer? I mean its a bad answer, but I didnt downvote it!

Comment: So, where are you stuck?

Comment: Hey I didn't downvote anyone. I really appreciate your answers. I should have probably mentioned that i have tried to console.log the array as well tried setInterval to not get it frozen up. But neither seems to be working. I normally don't use satckoverflow for homeworks but I have never coded in JS with cpu or memory usage in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Web worker and let it handle your request in the backend

In your html file

> index.html

```
<script>
 // Check if your browser supports worker
 if (window.Worker) {

 var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
 worker.postMessage("Start Logging");
 }
</script>
```

> worker.js

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  const result = e.data;
  if(result == "Start Logging"){
    for(let i = 1; i<= 1000000;i++){
      console.log(i)
    }
    postMessage('Done Loggind')
  }
  
}
```

[Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) can run your script in background without intercepting your main thread